# Bluetooth range is bad Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: bluetooth

So when I get around a meter away from my PC, the audio becomes laggy and somewhat 8-bit sounding, and if I get too far from the PC like 4 or 5 meters away, the device gets disconnected.
I'm sure the problem is not with my hardware because I didn't have the same issue on Windows.
any Help?

Answer (score 0):

I tried `hcitool` and `bluetoothctl` and had the same problem with both of them,so I Downloaded **Bluetooth Manager** from **Ubuntu Software** and the problem doesn't exist? *wtf*.